# how to clear application cache memory in ios devices?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

- In iOS device open settings-->General--> Storage & iCloud Usage --> Manage Storage -->  click on our application then here displaying documents & data. But can't clear documents and data
- In android platforms we clear applications cache memory. But in iPhone devices is there any way to do like that.

Comment: See my answer here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/281208/37364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feature like this on the iPhone. 
Try this: [PhoneExpander](http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TheIphoneBlog/~3/omINy5M1ieY/story01.htm)